# Apache Derby 10.15.* - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver

Tags: java, jdbc, driver, derby, classnotfoundexception

While trying to use Apache Derby DB (aka JavaDB, being once part of JDK) as an embedded in-memory DB for tests, I've encountered `ClassNotFoundException` thrown by HikariCP not being able to instantiate `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver`.

The project set up via Maven.
Derby dependency is:

```xml
<dependency>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <version>10.15.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

HikariCP configuration is:

```java
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:derby:memory:TestsDB;create=true");
return new HikariDataSource(config);
```

There are few threads that mention `ClientDriver` but I do need the `EmbeddedDriver` for in-memory JDBC access.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently things changed from Derby version `10.14.*` towards version `10.15.*`.

The latter (which I'm using) indeed has no such a class in its JAR.

After some search in the sources I've found that `org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver` has been moved to the tools JAR, so make sure to add the following dependency to your `pom.xml` too:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
    <version>10.15.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Note: of course, adjust the version of this artifact to be the same as the main one, whatever it is in your case.

To Apache Derby guys: if this change is intent-full, I suggest to change the main Derby artifact description, which still misleadingly states "Contains the core Apache Derby database engine, **which also includes the embedded JDBC driver**" (emphasis is mine [YG]).